# What stops you attempting to cast minor and significant formula spells repeatedly until you succeed?

Tags: unknown-armies

The rules for casting spells state that if you fail in casting a minor or significant spell, you don't lose the magical charge. There also do not seem to be any other drawbacks to rerolling until you get a success apart from the possibility of a matched failure. I am most interested in the situation out of combat, as in combat, you use your entire round by trying to cast the spell.

Given that this is the case, out of combat, is there anything in the rules that prevents/discourages someone from reattempting to cast a spell until they roll a success?

Note, I am firstly interested in whether there's anything I'm missing in the RAW, but should there not be, then I would find it helpful to hear if/how other people have handled this issue in games they have run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There isn't.**

As with the use of many skills in *Unknown Armies*, if you have uninterrupted time and a low-stress environment to set up your spell — particularly a formula spell — it should work as intended. The balancing factor for adept magic is the difficulty of getting charges; the die rolling is more of an obstacle in combat or other risky situations when you'll be trying again and again and running greater chances of getting a Sour Cherry.

Comment: +1. In UA, low/no-risk situations are basically narrative solely created by the players and GM, not a bag of dice.